# PostgreSQL 7.x archiving

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

I'm trying to get PostgreSQL 7.4 setup to use PITR mode (as described [here](http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.com/2009/02/simple-ha-with-postgresql-point-in-time.html)). It appears that the "archive_mode" option isn't recognised. Can anyone shed light on when this first appeared in PostgreSQL? I don't want to upgrade to a newer version unless I absolutely have to.

(For what it's worth, I was planning on using this to replicate PostgreSQL database updates across the wire to a warm standby database.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PITR was introduced in 8.0, as seen in feature list:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-0.html

> Point-In-Time Recovery
>
> ```
> In previous releases there was no way to recover from disk drive failure
> ```
>
> except to restore from a previous
>   backup or use a standby replication
>   server. Point-in-time recovery allows
>   continuous backup of the server. You
>   can recover either to the point of
>   failure or to some transaction in the
>   past.